# It's possible to control Chrome args with an extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension, same-origin-policy

I'm currently using a windows custom shortcut

```
chrome.exe --disable-site-isolation-trials --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="D:\temp"
```

it allows me to load and manipulate an external iframe.

My question is: It's possible to do this by creating or using a google chrome extension? If it's possible, can I do only for a specif domain?

Ps: I already tried some extensions like [Allow CORS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf) but they don't allow me to interact with the iframe.

Comment: No, but extensions don't need it because you can declare the content script to [run inside the iframe](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#frames) and then access its `document` directly.